# Doctrine orm mapping returns error Undefined index

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to write a code that maps two to entities but in the result, 
I get an error Undefined index: filterId

So without doctrine, the query is simple `SELECT * FROM filter f INNER JOIN filter_options fo ON f.id = fo.filter_id WHERE f = 1;`

So I need to get the same results as this query would give.

tables example:

```
filter

id|status
---------
1|active
2|active
3|active
```

```
filter_options:
id|filter_id|text
---------
1|1|lorem
2|1|ipsum
3|3|and
4|2|etc
```

Entity classes :

```
class Filter
{
   private $id;
   private $status;
   /**
    * @var FilterOption[]
    */
   private $options;
}

class FilterOption 
{
   private $id;
   private $filterId;
   private $text;
}
```

Filter.orm.xml:

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
   <generator strategy="AUTO" />
</id>
<field name="status" column="status"/>

<one-to-many field="options" target-entity="FilterOption" mapped-by="filterId"/>
```

FilterOption.orm.xml:

```
<id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
    <generator strategy="AUTO" />
</id>
<field name="text" column="text"/>

<field name="filterId" column="filter_id"/>
```

What I'm doing wrong. I want to get Filter entity in which property $options in an array with all other filterOptions entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about relation in Doctrine as of relation between objects, not as relation into database. Because of this you should not think about database columns like `filter_id` as plain properties, they needs to be replaced with actual entity associations instead.

In your case you need to replace plain `filterId` property into `FilterOption` entity with inverse side of Many-to-One association. Please refer Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) for details.

Your code may look something like this:

Filter.php

```
class Filter
{
   /**
    * @var int
    */
   private $id;
   /**
    * @var string
    */
   private $status;
   /**
    * @var FilterOption[]
    */
   private $options;
}
```

FilterOption.php

```
class FilterOption 
{
   /**
    * @var int
    */
   private $id;
   /**
    * @var Filter
    */
   private $filter;
   /**
    * @var string
    */
   private $text;
}
```

Filter.orm.xml:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="Filter" table="filter">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="status" column="status"/>
        <one-to-many field="options" target-entity="FilterOption" mapped-by="filter"/>
    </entity>
<doctrine-mapping>
```

FilterOption.orm.xml:

```
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="FilterOption" table="filter_option">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="text" column="text"/>
        <many-to-one field="filter" target-entity="Filter" inversed-by="options">
            <join-column name="filter_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </many-to-one>
    </entity>
<doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Is it normal that Filter option property has FilterOptios and FilterOptions has filter property which has Filter? In short, they both have each other so it's file infinite loop. I can call Filter and get the same Filter from Filter Options.

Comment: Yes, it is how associations are defined in Doctrine. I've added link to related article in Doctrine documentation into answer, you can take a look by yourself. Of course in a case of e.g. custom serialization process you will need to take care about this loop, but usually there is no problems with it because when you're fetching `Filter` from Doctrine - you're usually fetching it lazily and hence there is no actual `FilterOption` entities are available, instead there are proxy of them.